# Three20 - Getting empty TableView when setting a TTTableViewController as TableBannerView

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I have a TTTableViewController and want to show a tableBannerView (as shown [in the sample code](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTCatalog/Classes/TableWithBannerController.m)). The view to show is again a TTTableViewController:

```
- (void)toggleInfo {
  if(self.tableBannerView) {
    [self setTableBannerView:nil animated:YES];
  } else {
    CanteenInfoViewController *infoViewController = [[CanteenInfoViewController alloc] initWithCanteenID:[_canteen canteenID]];
    [self setTableBannerView:infoViewController.view animated:YES];
    [infoViewController release];
  }
}
```

However, when calling `[self toggleInfo]`, the tableBannerView that is shown is empty (I already checked that `[infoViewController createModel]`and `[infoViewController viewWillAppear:]` are called). 
When presenting infoViewController modally (`[self presentModalViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];`), it is shown correctly.

Can anyone give me a hint on what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Tilo

Comment: Can you put CanteenInfoViewController's `-initWithCanteenID:` and `loadView` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm... you create the infoViewController... set it's view as banner view... which probably increases the views retain count, but then you release the controller which results in a destruction of the controller(its retain count wasn't raised to 2), leaving it's view behind without a controller... are you sure that's what you want?